# Elasticsearch Document Count Doesn't Reflect Indexing Rate

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've indexing data from Spark into Elasticsearch, and according the Kibana, I'm indexing at a rate of 6k/s for the primary shards. However, if you look at the Document Count graph in the lower right, you'll see that it doesn't increase proportionately. How can this index have only 1.3k documents when it's indexing at 5 times that per second?

[image]

Comment: What is the key or _id for your index?

Comment: You seem to be comparing the no. of primary shards vs document count ?

Comment: If the document has nested properties the doc count number will be higher than the actual document count.

Comment: Do some of your documents have the same ID? if you index 10 documents with the same id (10 updates to the same document for instance), then the document count will not increase for sure